# Multiple conditions variables in bash script

Tags: bash

I need to do this:

```
if [ $X != "dogs" and "birds" and "dogs" ]
then
    echo "it's is a monkey"
fi
```

with bash script. How to proceed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to turn each option into a separate conditional expression, and then join them together with the `&&` (AND) operator.

```
if [[ $X != dogs && $X != birds && $X != cats ]]; then
  echo "'$X' is not dogs or birds or cats.  It must be monkeys."
fi
```

You can also do this with single `[`...`]`, but then you have to use a separate set for each comparison and move the and operator outside them:

```
if [ "$X" != dogs ] && [ "$X" != birds ] && [ "$X" != cats ]; then
   ...
fi
```

Note that you don't need double-quotes around single-word strings like `dogs`, but you do need them around parameter expansions (variables) like `$X` inside the single-bracket version, because a space in the value of the parameter will cause a syntax error without the quotes.

Also, there's no need to use uppercase variable names like `X`in shell scripts; that's best reserved for variables that come in from the environment, like `$PATH` and `$TERM` and so on.

The shell operator version of OR is `||`, which works the same way.

Comment: Note that you don't have to quote `$X` in double brackets, as `bash` does not perform word expansion on parameters in conditional expressions. `[[ $X != dogs ]]` would work even if `X="lassie scooby"`.

Comment: And how can i do this:  if [ $X != "dogs" OR "birds" OR "dogs" ] ? Seems || only accept two conditions...

Comment: @user2079266 - see edit.  OR is ||.  But the way you phrased it, the condition will always be true - `$X`cannot simultaneously be both dogs and birds, so it will always test as either not one or not the other.

Comment: @user2079266 - Do you want `[[ ! ( $X = dogs || $X = birds || $X = cats ) ]]`, which is equivalent to the && expression but with [DeMorgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) applied?

Comment: Within `[]`, you can use `-a` for `&&` and `-o` for `||`.

Answer (score 3):

#### Using consecutive tests

You can even think different...

```bash
if [[ $X == dogs || $X == birds || $X == cats ]]; then
    echo "'$X' is one of dogs, cats or birds."
else
    echo "'$X' is not dogs or birds or cats... It could be monkeys."
fi
```

Or else:

```bash
if ! [[ $X == dogs || $X == birds || $X == cats ]]; then
    echo "'$X' is not dogs or birds or cats... It could be monkeys."
fi
```

As thinking:

> it's not a dog AND not a cat and not a bird

is not exactly same as thinking

> it's not one of .. dog OR cat OR bird.

#### The `case`'s *switches* way

This make the approach of `case` more evident;
In fine, I think, for this kind of test, the right manner to do this is:

```bash
case $X in
    dogs )
        # There may be some part of code
        ;;
    birds )
        # There may be some other part
        ;;
    cats )
        # There is no need to be something at all...
       ;;          
    * )
       echo "'$X' is not dogs or birds or cats... It could be monkeys."
       ;;
esac
```

Or if there are really no need to process birds,cats or dogs case:

```bash
case $X in
    dogs|birds|cats ) ;;
    * )
       echo "'$X' is not dogs or birds or cats... It could be monkeys."
       ;;
esac
```

#### Little bench between two solutions

Doing three consecutive test is a bigger work than doing one `case` switching.

```bash
for X in dogs birds cats monkeys;do
    start=${EPOCHREALTIME/.}
    for i in {0..999}; do
        case $X in
            dogs|birds|cats ) res=0 ;;
            *) res=1;;
        esac
    done
    cres=$res cdur=$((${EPOCHREALTIME/.}-start))
    start=${EPOCHREALTIME/.}
    for i in {0..999}; do
        [[ $X == dogs || $X == birds || $X == cats ]]
        res=$?
    done
    tdur=$((${EPOCHREALTIME/.}-start))
    printf '  %-8s %d %9d %d %9d\n' $X $res $tdur $cres $cdur
done
```

This show a little table with 5 columns. On my raspberry-pi this output:

```
  dogs     0    387609 0    293285
  birds    0    460836 0    322203
  cats     0    555467 0    348978
  monkeys  1    518175 1    378782
```

- first columns is `$X` value
- second is `$res` value after 3 tests
- third is number of nanoseconds elapsed for using *tests* method
- fouth is `$res` value returned by *`case`* method
- last columns is *`case`* method duration in nanosec.

Hopefully, `$res` result is same, but `test` method duration are growing depending on number of tests. And mostly doing `test` seem more time expansive than `case`.

Comment: lol yes it could be monkeys I will up mark you for your cleverness of changing it from if to case :)

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of in Bash to avoid having to put $X multiple times is to use RegEx:

```
if [[ ! "$X" =~ (dogs|birds|cats) ]]; then
    echo "it's is a monkey"
fi
```

Similarly, in shorthand:

```
[[ ! "$X" =~ (dogs|birds|cats) ]] && echo "it's is a monkey"
```

This is helpful when you have very long variables, and/or very short comparisons.

Remember to escape special characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
X=$1;
if [ "$X" != "dogs" -a "$X" != "birds" -a "$X" != "dogs" ]
then
    echo "it's is a monkey"
fi
```

closest to what you already had